# Keyboard modifier keys begin prematurely acting like they are no longer pressed until reboot

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Occasionally, I will have one or more of the modifier keys pressed, but Windows acts as though it is not.  For example, while <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>-ing through tabs, suddenly one is selected and a tab character is entered into the document.  Or worse, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> enters a "v" rather than pasting from the clipboard.  This behavior starts seemingly out of nowhere, but once started, it continues sporadically until I reboot.  Perhaps coincidentally, today, it seemed to start around the time I used a four-key shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

I'm using Windows 7 with a [Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-keyboard-elite/A11-00337) keyboard (my long-time favorite).  The keyboard is plugged in via USB into a Dell docking station.

Is this most likely a hardware or software issue?  If it's hardware, Microsoft has been good about replacing faulty products.  Otherwise, if it could be software, is there a known solution, or something I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You either will need a new keyboard (try another cheap one if you have one lying around to verify), or you have something accidentally turned on in the Easy of Access center in Windows 7.

Start Menu Search -> Easy of Access Center -> Make the keyboard easier to use - Make sure nothing in here is turned on.