# Modifier keys on laptop's integrated keyboard are non-responsive occasionally?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, asus-laptop

I recently bought an ASUS laptop which seemed to work very well. After using it for a while I noticed that occasionally when doing commands such as `CTRL + S`, `SHIFT + A` (any letter really) or `ALT + TAB` with the integrated keyboard it would ignore the `ctrl`, `shift` or `alt`. Instead it would just do the `S`, `A` or `TAB` and I had to repeatedly press the modifier / command key(s) in order for it to start working again. I noticed at one point when it was happening that it seemed to only affect the left-side modifier keys as right-control would work when left-control wouldn't. It also seems to affect "all" at once.

I went through most of the support sites and called ASUS support which suggested it was a hardware specific reason. I followed all of the steps which included:

1. Reinstalling drivers
2. Changing keyboard settings in windows
3. Using the windows troubleshooter
4. Reinstalled windows

The thing which *bothers* me the most is that due to the random occurrence (it can happen 8/10 times in a row while not happening for several minutes after that) I am not sure how to accurately replicate it. I tried to press the keys repeatedly for a period of time when having the windows on-screen keyboard where it did seem like the keys were lose due to them *flickering* in the on-screen keyboard.

To not break warranty I haven't done anything to the keyboard but  before sending it to repairs **I am just wondering if I am missing something or is it most likely faulty hardware?**

**Laptop:** ASUS ExpertBook B1 (B1402)

**Other SU related posts:**

1. [Keyboard modifier keys begin prematurely acting like they are no longer pressed until reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/328583/keyboard-modifier-keys-begin-prematurely-acting-like-they-are-no-longer-pressed)
2. [Control key acts as if it is stuck periodically](https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically)

Comment: To avoid this being a dead end for future users: I did send the laptop for repairs and they replaced the integrated keyboard (idk if they did anything to the motherboard) but after that it has been working until now and there are lights on the left-hand-side (where the the issue was) that are glowing now so it seems to indeed have been a hardware failure.